# Recuperar registros de la base de datos mediante jquery y ajax

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Tengo el siguiente fullCalendar

```
 var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'local',
    plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
    defaultView: 'timeGridDay',
    defaultDate: hoy,
    header: header,
    forceEventDuration: true,
    businessHours: [ // specify an array instead
        {
            daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            startTime: '09:00', // 8am
            endTime: '21:00' // 6pm
        }
    ],
    minTime: "09:00",
    maxTime: "21:00",

    events: [{
        title: 'Agustin Guerra',
        start: '2020-03-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2020-03-12T11:30:00'
    }]
```

Como verán, la propiedad `events` tiene un dato estático. Yo en la base de datos tengo dos registros

`ID 1 | DATOS {"title":"Agustin Guerra","start":"2020-03-13T09:30:00","end":"2020-03-13T10:30:00"}`

`ID 2 | DATOS {"title":"Maria Marco","start":"2020-03-13T13:00:00","end":"2020-03-13T14:00:00"}`

> Tambien tengo creadas las funciones en el controlador y en el modelo para recuperar los elementos de la base de datos

**controlador**

```
    static public function ctrMostrarTurnos(){

    $respuesta = ModeloTurnos::mdlMostrarTurnos();

    return $respuesta;

     }
```

**modelo**

```
static public function mdlMostrarTurnos(){

        $tabla = "turnos";

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }
```

Yo quisiera obtener mediante `ajax` todos los registros de la base de datos en el momento en que se carga la pagina, para colocarlos uno a uno en un string, y que este sea el valor de la propiedad `events`, para, de esta forma, llenar el calendario dinamicamente.

No se bien como realizar un ajax de este tipo, ya que yo no deberia mandarle al archivo php ninguna variable (como lo estuve haciendo en otros casos), sino que deberia hacer una solicitud para obtener todos los registros de la tabla. No pretendo que realicen el codigo por mi, pero si me linkean a algun buen ejemplo de como hacer esto (obtener todos los registros de una tabla mediante ajax en el momento que se carga la pagina) estaria muy agradecido.